# Specific Application Fonts showing Small in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 with dell latitude e7470 system and then installed application on it.

In some of application like Notepad ++, Zoom for Desktop i am seeing that fonts of menu bar and other content inside application is appearing too small. Even same for some other application as well.

[Notepad++ issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzzQS.png)

What is the solution to get rid of this issue?

Comment: SO is for programming questions only. Please ask on [ubuntu.se] or [su] instead.

Comment: Did you ask on Ask Ubuntu? Could you share the link? I'm running into the exact same issue with other software.

Comment: I did not raise ticket in ubuntu, and event after upgrading ubuntu 21 still issue is persist.

So i believe this issue is related to ubuntu integration with HD monitor system.

Comment: I am planning the same, ubuntu for that model. The Dell website tells it recommends the Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @JovylleBermudez : But to use old version is not good deal right ? Latest version of Ubuntu should be compatible with any flavour of system.